# Can you save/view a video file and sensor data simultaneously

Tags: android, video, sensors

I am very new to Java programming language and I was wondering if I were to collect sesnor data along with video recording would I be able to save the both sets of data and then open both set of data to review them simultaneously.

I am collecting pressure data and video recording of what causes the pressure to change. I hope to display a graph of the data and the video while I collect data. I want to know if its possible for me to save both sets of data and then be able to reopen both sets of data and review them next to each other in order to see when the pressure increased and visually see what caused the pressure increase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
You will need to do your video capturing in one thread, and the data logging in the other(saving sensors and timestamp).
Keep in mind that once you have managed to store the data (from both streams), you will need to do some synchronization between them. 
By means of some preprocessing, you will have to retrieve the logged data that corresponds to the time of each video frame.
Once this is done, you could then, play your video along with synced sensor data that was collected along with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, and I found this :

https://github.com/e-lab/VideoSensors

> App that records video and motion data from an android smartphone
>   simultaneously. The app lets you choose the video quality and the rate
>   at which data is saved. It can be used to record video and
>   accelerometer, gyroscope, compass, GPS data at the same time

I don't know if it works...
seems a bit dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to modulate the captured sensor data into an audio signal, perhaps that could then be saved as an audio track within the video recording file itself, or to a separate audio format file.

This would ensure synchronization even if the video was later processed. As long as the audio track remains, the data could be demodulated and decoded at any future point.

Data could be modulated at audible frequencies (i.e. like an old analog computer modem) that could be heard during playback, or at a higher or lower frequency (i.e. so that the data could co-exist with other audio - if there was no other audio, the video could be played on any device without first having to strip out your modulated data and would seem silent).

Alternatively, instead of saving your data as audio, you could store it into a standard subtitling format (e.g. ‘.srt’); this might be easier to do in Java in a platform-agnostic way. When playing back the video, your recorded data could then (optionally) display as subtitles directly on top of the video (using a common player, such as VLC) without necessarily requiring any post-processing.

When the video recording begins, store the start time in a variable. Each time you want to log a new piece of data, subtract that stored ‘start time’ from the current time (giving you ‘time elapsed from start of recording’), and you’ll have all the data you need to keep such a plain-text subtitle data file. If you keep all of these data points and their corresponding relative/elapsed times in an array, you can wait until the video recording is complete to create the plaintext subtitle file. It’s no crash-safe, but the implementation may be simpler.